# OpenVPN cannot route traffic

Tags: iptables, openvpn

Scenario

OpenVPN server running on Gentoo

eno1: (server public ip) has static ip... NO dhcp

eno2: vlan (down for now)

tun0: openvpn tunnel interface

server.conf

```
local <external ip>
port 443
proto tcp
dev tun

ca              ca.crt
cert            cert.crt
key             key.key
dh              dh.pem
tls-auth        hmac.key 0

server          10.77.198.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

push            "redirect-gateway def1"
push            "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"

keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
max-clients 10
user nobody
group nobody

persist-key
persist-tun

status          /var/log/openvpn-status.log
log             /var/log/openvpn.log
log-append      /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 4
```

client.conf

```
client
remote <server ext ip>
port 443
comp-lzo
dev tun
proto tcp

persist-key
persist-tun
verb 4

<ca>
removed
</ca>

<cert>
removed
</cert>

<key>
removed
</key>

key-direction 1
<tls-auth>
removed
</tls-auth>
```

Connecting from Win7 x64 machine

...works fine

i am being assigned an ip from 10.77.198.0 pool

i can ping the server's external ip from the client

ISSUE:

traffic is not routed through the vpn

```
route -n

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         <ext ip>.254    0.0.0.0         UG    2      0        0 eno1
10.77.198.0     10.77.198.2     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.77.198.2     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
<ext ip>.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno1
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eno2
```

Am i missing anything, apart from the iptables rules?

If not, please provide a COMPLETE set of iptables rules to properly route traffic between tun0 and eno1. Keep in mind eno1 has a static ip.

P.S.

Gateway being pushed to the client is from 10.77.198.0 pool also

Answer (score 0):

Solved by enabling ip_forward
and following the example at

https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/BridgingAndRouting